# software VPN via Ubuntu & osX

Tags: ubuntu, mac-osx, vpn, openvpn, hamachi

I want to be able to access my shared folders on my ubuntu server from my laptop (osX) when I'm at Uni. I'd prefer to set up a VPN and continue to use the SMB or AFP (if i can get it working) that I use at home.

What would be the best solution to implement a VPN between the 2 computers, I would like the ability to add my other win7 laptop too at some stage down the line.

I've had a quick look over openVPN and hamachi but not sure what would be the best. I'm not going to be transferring 50mb+ but I would like access to everything on it.

any pointers, suggestions or guides?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest macfuse http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/ to access via sshfs.
Expandrive is another great tool (not free).
Other pointers for a vpn is http://www.remobo.com or http://www.teamviewer.com
Expandrive, remobo and teamviewer works with Win7.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely suggest using openvpn....

Its fantastic :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use n2n, which works well and is less complicated to set up.

If you use openvpn, I suggest using Tunnelblick as the GUI for it.